# Backfill dates using CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table with IDs and with null startdate. I am trying to back fill them using CTE.

If the EndDate is '2011-12-31' for Record#1, the StartDate for Record#2 is EndDate from Record#1 + 1 day i.e. '2012-01-01'

```
Create table dbo.input(inputid int null,startDate smalldatetime null,endDate smalldatetime null)
 insert into dbo.input values(111,null,'2011-05-31')
 insert into dbo.input values(111,null,'2012-05-31')
 insert into dbo.input values(111,null,'2013-05-31')
 insert into dbo.input values(111,null,'2014-05-31')
 insert into dbo.input values(111,null,'2015-05-31')


 insert into dbo.input values(222,null,'2010-06-30')
 insert into dbo.input values(222,null,'2011-06-30')
 insert into dbo.input values(222,null,'2012-06-30')
 insert into dbo.input values(222,null,'2013-06-30')
 insert into dbo.input values(222,null,'2014-06-30')
```

This is the expected output.

```
 Create table dbo.output(outputid int null,startDate smalldatetime null,endDate smalldatetime null)
 insert into dbo.output(111,null,'2011-05-31')
 insert into dbo.output(111,'2011-06-01','2012-05-31')
 insert into dbo.output(111,'2012-05-31','2013-05-31')
 insert into dbo.output(111,'2013-05-31','2014-05-31')
 insert into dbo.output(111,'2014-05-31','2015-05-31')


 insert into dbo.output(222,null,'2010-06-30')
 insert into dbo.output(222,'2010-06-30','2011-06-30')
 insert into dbo.output(222,'2011-06-30','2012-06-30')
 insert into dbo.output(222,'2012-06-30','2013-06-30')
 insert into dbo.output(222,'2013-06-30','2014-06-30')
```

This is what I tried

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by p.inputid ORDER BY p.inputid,endDate),
        p.inputid
       ,EndDate
FROM dbo.input p
)
SELECT distinct
DATEADD(day,1,prev.enddate) as startd,cte.inputid,cte.endDate
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rn = CTE.rn - 1
LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rn = CTE.rn + 1
order by cte.inputid,startd
```

It is not grouping by inputid properly and I do not know how to fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
MR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting your existing query, but results are not exactly same as your expected. Should StartDate be next day of previous EndDate? (not same day as the previous EndDate.)

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT
                   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by inputid ORDER BY endDate)
               , *
            FROM #input 
)

SELECT a.inputid, DATEADD(DD, 1, b.endDate) as startDate , a.endDate
FROM CTE a
LEFT JOIN CTE b 
    ON  a.inputid = b.inputid and a.rn = b.rn + 1
ORDER BY a.inputid, a.startDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use the following...

```
 SELECT 
    i.inputid,
    startDate = DATEADD(dd, 
                        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.inputid, i.endDate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
                        LAG(i.endDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY i.inputid ORDER BY i.endDate)
                        ),
    i.endDate
 FROM 
    #input i;
```